# NSBundle not ye loaded localizable strings

Tags: objective-c, localization, nsbundle

I am trying to dynamically load an other localizable file to translate my viewController.

```
NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];
if (bundlePath == nil)
    self.bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
else{
    self.bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
    if(!self.bundle)
        self.bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
} 

// Example of translation
NSString* frenchWord = [self.bundle localizedStringForKey:englishWord value:@"" table:nil];
```

But when I'm debugging it seems that the bundle is not loaded yet. And "frenchWord" is always equals to englishWord .. But the NSFileManager tells me that my bundle path is correct..

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bundlePath] // => return YES
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: what is your localize string file name?

Comment: Localizable.strings in fr.lproj folder of my project